# Python continue after Exception

Tags: python, exception

i know this question has been asked already, but i doesn't get a solution yet.
I assume that this exception should continue the for loop, but it doesn't.
Have spent some time trying to resolve this issue but i cant find any good solution.
Got any idea?

```
for store in CREATE:
    #print "Create ticket:"
    print '-' * 80
    print store.storeNumber, store.date

    br.open(OPEN_NEW_CASE_URL)
    form = br.select_form("selsite01")
    try:
        #assert store.internalID
        br["site_id"] = [store.internalID]
    except AttributeError:
        CREATE.remove(store) # if store is not found on the m***** drop down field
        print "[WARNING] Store", store.storeNumber ,"not found in the ticket list, could not create."
        continue
    br.submit()


    """ Build ticket from config file """
    br.select_form("newcase")
    [.... more code ....]
br.open(LOGOUT_URL) # be nice and logout
```

edit (solved the issue):

```
    try:
        #assert store.internalID
        br["site_id"] = [store.internalID]
    except AttributeError:
        print "[WARNING] Store", store.storeNumber ,"not found in the ticket list, could not create."
        continue
    br.submit()
```

Comment: Please show the output of the program when you attempt to run it.

Comment: removing store from CREATE within the loop is not a good idea.

Comment: removing store from CREATE was a stupid an unecessary idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jayanth Koushik pointed out removing items from a list while iterating over it causes this error.